# Extracting data using Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to extract the 2 data from the below code. Can anyone tell me the Selenium webdriver code to extract this.

Data to be fetched:

1. URL (//asset1.marksandspencer.com/is/image/mands/SD_01_T41_4350_X9_X_EC_88?$PDP_SWL_STD$)
2. Colour: Sapphire

Below is the HTML code in which the data is present.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="swatch-container">
        <div class="product-carousels swatch-carousel">
            <div class="caro typeB swatchContainerHeight" data-touch-skip-components-init="true" data-carousel="{" single " : false, "title " : true, "wrap " : ".custom-wrap ", "prev " : "Prev ", "next " : "Next ", "preset " : "PDP_SWL_STD "}" data-alt-image-text="Default Alt">
                <ul class="custom-wrap swatches grid-variant-swatches">
                    <li class="all ">
                        <li class="all active-swatch">
                            <div class="selected-swatch" />
                            <input id="Sapphire" type="radio" data-subset-viewer="http://www.marksandspencer.com/MSLightboxDisplayView?catalogId=10051&langId=-24&productId=2559515&storeId=10151" data-alt-image-text="Sapphire Pure Cotton T-Shirt with StayNEW™ Clothing" data-image-set="//asset1.marksandspencer.com/is/image/mands/T41_4350_X9_IS?req=imageset,json&id=T41_4350_X9_IS" data-dressipi="sapphire" value="Sapphire" name="colour" checked="checked" />
                            <label class="colour-1 lazy" style="background-image:url(//asset1.marksandspencer.com/is/image/mands/SD_01_T41_4350_X9_X_EC_88?$PDP_SWL_STD$)" data-swatch-name="Sapphire" for="Sapphire">
                                <span class="glimmer-container" />
                            </label>
                        </li>
```

Below is the code I am using:

```
WebElement productname = driver.findElement(By.className("content").className("colour-1 lazy"));
String image = productname.getAttribute("Style");
System.out.println(image);
```

Comment: Hi, Please find the code below which I am using but is not helping me out.                      'code'                                                                  WebElement productname = driver.findElement(By.className("content").className("colour-1 lazy"));
  String image=productname.getAttribute("Style");
  System.out.println(image);    'code'

Comment: When you post HTML please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ to properly format it. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I have enough information to give the best answer but I can provide an answer based on what you have provided.

All the data you are asking for is in the `LABEL` tag. You can find it using a CSS selector `label.colour-1` which means find a `LABEL` tag that has a class (.) `colour-1`. Once you have the element, you can get the `data-swatch-name` attribute for the color name, Sapphire. Then you get the `style` attribute and parse it for the URL portion.

```
WebElement swatch = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label.colour-1"));
String color = swatch.getAttribute("data-swatch-name");
System.out.println(color); // Sapphire
String style = swatch.getAttribute("style");
System.out.println(style.substring(style.indexOf(":") + 1)); // url(//asset1.marksandspencer.com/is/image/mands/SD_01_T41_4350_X9_X_EC_88?$PDP_SWL_STD$)
```